# Nodejs SQL connections and async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I been playing along with Node.JS and I found this great async library https://github.com/caolan/async. I want to replace the traditional callback model with this, as it looks a bit more pleasing and easier to understand.

This is my code for sql query

```
function query_mssql(config, sql_string){
  var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
  // ... error checks 

  if (err) {
    console.log('connection to mssql has failed');
    //throw err;
  }else{

    // Query 
    var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection.request(); 
    request.query(sql_string, function(err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks should go here :

        // output query result to console:
        console.log(recordset);
        return recordset;
    });

  }
```

});
}

I am wondering how to make this async, like the example given in the library.

```
    async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
   ],
   // optional callback
   function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
   });
```

Can someone help me with this? I don't quite understand how the error reporting works.

Based on Chris's comment, how exactly will the waterfall method help if called in multi layered?

```
function computeCurrentDefinitionResult(database, node_name) {
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      var leaf_sql_query = "SELECT * FROM "+  JSON.stringify(database)  +".dbo.LeafNode WHERE NodeName=" + "'" + node_name + "'";
      query_mssql_internal(leaf_sql_query, callback);
      console.log('Might BE HAPPY');
    },
], function(err, recordset) {
    // ... error checks should go here :
    if (err) {
        console.log('mssql query has failed');
    }

    // output query result to console:
    console.log(recordset);
    return recordset;
  });

function query_mssql_internal(sql_string){
  return query_mssql(config, sql_string);
}
```

the "query_mssql()" call your function. How do pass on result back to top calling function or the error back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I believe you should use [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) since you want to pass results along each async task.

Here is a quick example below. You'll have to edit it to suit your needs.

If an error happens in a task, it'll move out to the optional method at the end.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        var connection = new sql.Connection(config, 
            function(err) {
                callback(err, connection)
            }
        );
    },
    function(connection, callback) {
        var request = connection.request(); 
        request.query(sql_string, callback);
    }
], function(err, recordset) {
    // ... error checks should go here :

    // output query result to console:
    console.log(recordset);
});
```

As you see, you can add parameters after the error in your callback and then receive them in the next task. This is a feature of [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall).

Here is a test example as well...

```
require("should");
var async = require("async");
describe("async test", function() {
   it('should do stuff', function(done){

       async.waterfall([
           function(callback){
               a(callback);
           },
           function(aResult, callback){
               b(callback, aResult);
           }
       ], function(err, aResult, bResult) {
           console.log(aResult + " " + bResult);
           done();
       });

       function a(callback) {
           callback(null, 1);
       }
       function b(callback, aResult) {
           callback(null, aResult, 2);
       }

   })
});
```

As for your last edit, you must return your value asynchronously. So you cannot use a return statement to get your result. This has a trickle effect which causes those dependencies to become asynchronous as well.

Comment: This won't going to work: you're not calling the `callback` without the error in the first function, same thing in the second one. You should necessarily do that, to let `async` know you're done and it can execute the next function.

Comment: I am assuming that the error will be null from those functions if they are successful.  I think it is Ok under that assumption.

Comment: Can you explain? I did not understand the "async know you're done".

Comment: Chris, This is quite interesting, but will this method work when I use multi layerd calls? I will write a separate comment explaining this.

Comment: @Cris Ok, but even if the error is `null`, you should call the callback, like `callback(null, connection)`, otherwise the `waterfall` function will never be notified that you have finished what you're doing.

Comment: But isn't callback(err, connection) the same as callback(null, connection) if err is null?

Comment: @Chris, how do pass on the error to top calling function? I put the sample code in above post

Comment: I added to this answer. You have to get the value back asynchronously (through a callback). You can't use a return statement.